# how use model in emberJS pod structure?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, asp.net-web-api, ember-cli

i use pods structure in ember. i want to create a dataservice and a dropdown component. which way is the best?
my structure is based on ember-cli.

**these are what i did before:**

this is my pods structure: 
[image]

code in dropdown/route.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
     var store = this.store;
     return  $.ajax({
        url: 'http://.../api/Category/Categories', //my api url
        type: 'get'
       }).then(function(items) {            
         items.forEach(function(item, index, enumerable) {
            store.push('model',{
                id:item.Id,
                name: item.Title,
                value: item.Id.toString()
            });
         });
      });
     }
  });
```

codes in dropdown/model.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember-data';

export default Ember.Model.extend({
    name: Ember.attr('string'),
    value: Ember.attr('string')   
});
```

in my dropdown page , i have this error:

> Error: No model was found for 'model'

how can i solve that?

which way is better? using way above or using restadapter and serializer?
if second way is better, please help me how can i that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your pods structure is a little bit wrong. Pods structure is used to wrap resources in your app. Accordingly to [ember-cli docs](http://www.ember-cli.com/#pod-structure) you should split the directories in resource-manner, where each directory can contain three files:

- controller.js
- route.js
- template.hbs

Or in case of component:

- component.js
- template.hbs

What I can propose you is:

- move your model to `models` directory above `pods` (and probably change the name, as `Model` may cause some strange behaviour)
- leave the dropdown component where it is
- I am not sure, but if your `dataservice` is a service instead of the component, move it to `services` directory, above `pods`

Models should be define in `models` directory, not in pods structure. Moreover, it looks like you are using ember-data (using `store`), but you create your models by extending `Ember.Model`. I am not sure if the more proper approach would be to extend `DS.Model` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my structure is true, try to create resource in commandlilne, it adds each model to its route's folder ,same mine.

Answer (score 1):

This is how your pods folder shoulds end up (Components example ) :

```
  ├── app
  │  ├── pods
  │  │  └── components
  │  │     └── x-foo
  │  │     │  ├── component.js
  │  │     │  └── template.hbs
  │  │     └── x-bar
  │  │        ├── component.js
  │  │        └── template.hbs
```

(Models example)

```
  ├── app
  │  ├── pods
  │  │  └── foo
  │  │     │  ├── controller.js
  │  │     │  ├── route.js
  │  │     │  └── template.hbs
  │  │  └── bar
  │  │     │  ├── controller.js
  │  │     │  ├── route.js
  │  │     │  └── template.hbs
```

Learn more about "pod" structure [here](http://www.ember-cli.com/#pod-structure).

Answer (score 0):

i changed my route.js : 
 `store.push('model',...)` to  `store.push('dropdown',...)` 
and it works fine.

Comment: Very nice to hear this, didn't know it loads models also. Thanks!